# Pandas v. SFrame in learning data science

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, pandas

I'm taking a machine learning course that introduces the related assignments as such that a student may use either Pandas or SFrame in solving them. As a beginner, it's hard for me to assess which approach would be more beneficial for me in the long run. Hence the question; should I prefer Pandas or SFrame for learning purposes?

Initially I might've preferred Pandas to make sure I learn the "proper foundations" first, so to speak. However, after reading about this online, SFrame appears to be very popular after having been made open source. Can it be considered a Pandas replacement from a (future) data scientist's point of view?

Thanks a bunch! Protips always welcome in comments ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFrame is not used much in industry, so I'd stick to pandas or **Spark** DataFrames. But they're all rather similar, and you should not spend much time thinking about it: it is easy to pick these things up, and employers understand this. Concentrate on the algorithms; that's the real "foundation", not the tools.